# How can build a website for multiple organization?

Tags: 7

I am going to build a Drupal 7 website with this structure.

- Drupal admin create organizations, the organization is separated.
- In each organization, it will be have an organization admin who is
  assigned by Drupal admin.
- Each organization will have their own taxonomy. The taxonomy are
  created on one vocabulary.
- Organization admin is able to create Project.
- Organization can create users (called organization user) in their
  organization and assign what project users can working on.
- Organization users can create some nodes and those nodes are
  separated in each project they are working on.

My questions are: 1) How I can do like that? and 2) What modules can be used to do it?

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty much exactly what the [OG](http://dgo.to/og) (Organic Groups) module is for.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that [Organic Groups](https://drupal.org/project/og) is great for this.

But also [Open Atrium](https://drupal.org/project/openatrium).  The it is a Drupal distribution that has everything you request.

See also separate website: [OpenAtrium.com](http://openatrium.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Open Atrium will be good.Interestingly surfing around for alternate options I found [project management](https://drupal.org/project/pm) module.I guess its worth having a look.